# How to set the WebBrowser object in the .NET Framework to use whatever highest version of IE is installed on the users system

Tags: c#, .net, request

So the title says it all, I would like C# code (so please, PLEASE make sure it isn't Visual Basic code). And that is all I want to ask. I have tried the web browser built in to the .NET framework, but it looks like some old version of IE (if I am right or not). And if you answered, well thanks I guess! I need this for a small project where a bot would just log on to a website (its a base for future projects).

Comment: Its 2019. Microsoft has already abandoned IE and so should you (if possible ofc)

Comment: Visual Studio uses IE by default, I don't wanna poke around too much with Awesomium and stuff as I'm no expert and can screw things up a bit.

Answer (score -2):

By default it's IE7. You can bang a registry entry in to make it later:

```
public static void EnsureBrowserEmulationEnabled(string exename = "YourAppName.exe", bool uninstall = false)
{

    try
    {
        using (
            var rk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(
                    @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true)
        )
        {
            if (!uninstall)
            {
                dynamic value = rk.GetValue(exename);
                if (value == null)
                    rk.SetValue(exename, (uint)11001, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            }
            else
                rk.DeleteValue(exename);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Code courtesy of [this blog](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/may/21/web-browser-control-specifying-the-ie-version)

The values you can use in place of 11001 can be found [in MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/ee330730(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#browser_emulation)

Alternatively; can you do what you want by using WebClient/HttpWebRequest rather than poking at a web browser control to navigate around? Or can you find some web service/api version of the site that will respond with JSON rather than trying to manipulate html?

I was mildly curious why you'd care what a page looks like if it's a bot that is using it, but perhaps you're hitting a "your IE is too old" from the server..

Comment: So 1 answer, 1 question to ask for me. The answer: I just want to poke around, I want to directly interfere with HTML elements directly, like putting text in a textbox (sorry if I sound kinda dumb, I am pretty bad at server stuff and all). And the question, where to the code? I dumped it in Form1.vb and didn't see it working... Regardless, thanks for answering!

Comment: Ok, I was asking where to put the code, and I mistook .cs for .vb (so sorry for the confusion), so you kind of misunderstood me I think. So where to put it?

Comment: It wouldn't really matter so long as you call it to write the necessary registry entries...

Comment: I'm not too sure, I tried putting it in Form1.cs and a C# class. Sorry if this is annoying, but when things don't work I just got to ask.

Comment: Can you edit the question to say what you did, and more accurately define "doesn't work"